# is it possible to force a table to display 'x' amount of rows?

Tags: php, html

is it possible to force a table to display e.g. 10 rows - no matter what, even if the rows are blank?

my code is as so:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Date Created</th>
</tr>
<?php
    try {
        $pages = new Paginator('10','p');

        $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID FROM article_posts');

        $pages->set_total($stmt->rowCount());

        $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM article_posts ORDER BY postID DESC '.$pages->get_limit());
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'. $row['postTitle'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.date('jS M Y', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</td>';
                echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';

        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
</table>
<?php echo $pages->page_links(); ?>
```

i have the records output and pagination into rows of 10, however, if there is a number such as 26 records, then i get just six rows on one page.

its more of a design frustration of mine for wanting to do this as the page alters (everything moves up) and i want everything to keep form. i guess i could put the table inside a fixed div to prevent  this, but would like to know if this way is possible, and i guess is it a 'bad' way to do this over selecting the div method. i am thinking of in the future allowing the user to increase/decrease the amount of results shown, so e.g. 10, 20, 50... would forcing the table to display a set number of rows be a 'bad' idea when approaching this?

Comment: *would forcing the table to display a set number of rows be a 'bad' idea when approaching this?* as a user i would find it odd

Comment: Count how many rows you have after you've inserted the values from the db, subtract them from 10 and then use a for-loop to fill the placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Charlotte's comment, this is a way of doing it:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['postTitle'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.date('jS M Y', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</td>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $i++;
}
while ($i < 10){
    echo '<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>';
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here. First, if table cells are completely empty, their height is by default zero. You can fix this by setting `height` on them; for cells, it acts as minimum height. For brevity, I’ll use just 4 rows here.

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.3; /* set to a specific value */
}
.x td {
  height: 1.3em; /* one line, since line height is 1.3 */
}
```

```html
<table border>
  <tr><td>foo</td>
  <tr><td>bar</td>
  <tr><td></td>
  <tr><td></td>
</table>

Same with min height set:

<table border class=x>
  <tr><td>foo</td>
  <tr><td>bar</td>
  <tr><td></td>
  <tr><td></td>
</table>
```

The other issue is the amount of `tr` elements in tables. This is best handled in the generation process by just keeping track of the amount of rows and emitting some empty rows when needed. You might then consider including no-break spaces as content, e.g. ` , since it causes the cells to have the height of one line, and you would not need the CSS code.